# Why my SSD writes count increases so fast with a browsing use?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

One year ago, I bought a Thinkpad T460s with a 512GB SSD NVMe.
I haven't done anything special with it and I don't handle big files, mainly browsing using Windows 10.

Yesterday, I was checking my other external drives and I have discovered my SSD has 6TB of writes and a bit more in reading!!! It means 12 times full disk writes.

Yesterday's value was **6273GB** and this morning, with a bit of browsing (really nothing else), it's now at **6282GB** in 3hours power on hours. That means something wrote **9GB** within **3h** with just browsing.

How this is possible? How can I monitor that? I am very afraid for my SSD life. Even my previous 4-5years old V300 has only 10TB writes with more intensive uses.

I don't use any antivirus or anything that could consume disk writes. Is it windows 10?

I hope Windows 10 disabled the defragmentation feature and everything else that could impact the SSD's life.

Comment: How much memory does your system have?

Comment: 8GB and barely used 3GB when watching video or doing my stuff

Comment: Its time to run **Process Monitor**  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon    It will tell you what is writing to your hard drive.  Note click the icons to turn off registry,process, and network monitoring as it will create hundreds of thousands of log entries you don't need to see.